# Maximize a function containing Max

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I am trying to maximize a function (involving several Max and Min) in two variables and one parameter with some constraints. After struggling with it, I am trying with smaller examples to understand what I am doing wrong. I write here the three small examples I am working on:

1) 2 variables and 1 parameter:

```
    Maximize[100 g x - 1/6 y + x, 0 < y < 10 && 0 < x < 10 && g > 0, {x, y}]
```

which gives the solution:

```
    10 (1 + 100 g), g>0 
    -\[Infinity], True
```

{x -> Indeterminate, y -> Indeterminate}}

2) 2 variables and a Max:

```
    Maximize[100  x - 1/6 y + Max[0, x], 0 < y < 10 && 0 < x < 10 , {x, y}]
```

which gives the solution:

```
   1010, {x -> 10, y -> 0}
```

3) 2 variables, 1 parameter and a Max:

```
   Maximize[100 g x - 1/6 y + Max[0, x], g > 0 && 0 < y < 10 && 0 < x < 10 , {x,y}]
```

which does not solve the problem; just gives this solution:

```
    Maximize[100 g x - 1/6 y + Max[0, x], g > 0 && 0 < y < 10 && 0 < x < 10 ,{x,y}].
```

Now my question is: why the combination of case 1) and 2) together does not work?

Thank you very much!

Comment: I don't understand. If you assume `x>0`, then `Max[x, 0]=x`. Why you need `Max` function?

Answer (score 1):

Make the intervals half-closed (or closed)

```
Assuming[g > 0, 
 Maximize[{100 g x - 1/6 y + x, 0 <= y < 10, 0 < x <= 10}, {x, y}] // 
  Simplify]

(* {10 + 1000 g, {x -> 10, y -> 0}} *)
```

**EDIT:**

```
Assuming[{g > 0, x > 0}, 
 Maximize[{100 g x - 1/6 y + Max[x, 0], 0 <= y <= 10, 
    0 < x <= 10}, {x, y}] // Simplify]

(* {10 + 1000 g, {x -> 10, y -> 0}} *)
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. However, this suggestion still does not work when I have to maximize a function containing a Max, e.g.: 
         Assuming[g > 0, Maximize[{100 g x - 1/6 y + Max[x, 0], 0 <= y <= 10, 0 < x <= 10}, {x, y}] // Simplify], which cannot be solved..

Comment: The OP contains both the constraints and the use of Max. I agree that the Max is redundant. Reiterating part of the constraint is necessary to help the Simplify deal with the Piecewise.